# How to grep from a list and create an individual file for each grep search?

Tags: bash

I have 50 files, each of these files have lines where a value of interest is present for example "2TQMY".

The files end with .annotation so I can do this: grep "2TQMY" *.annotations and I will obtain all the lines across the different annotation files with the "2TQMY" value.

The problem is that I have over 180 files with values like "2TQMY" slightly different from each other, I've been trying to create a loop where I can obtain 180 files one for each of the 180 values across the 50 files.

So something like `grep "2TQMY" *.annotations` done 180 times for each of the 180 values.

I tried this

```
while read i; do grep $i *.annotations; done < lists_values
```

but I get a single file where all of the 180 values are found across my 50 files and in this case I need 180 files so I am a bit stuck.

I was wondering i there was a loop or command i could use for this specifically, thanks a lot beforehand for your help.

Comment: Thanks a lot , this is exactly what i needed, its done do i need to close the thread or upvote something similar ?

Comment: I should point out that this is going to be relatively slow if simply due to the repeated reads of the files; a faster approach would likely use some other tool (eg, `awk`) to only read each input file once but would then need to deal with how to manage 180 output files

Comment: Don't use a shell loop calling grep many times for this as it'll be extremely slow and probably buggy, just use 1 call to awk. If you [edit] your question to provide concise, testable sample input and expected output then we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

One approach:

```
grep $i *.annotations > $i.results
```

If you choose to name the new files `$i.annotations` then make sure you write these new files to a different directory otherwise each pass through the loop you'll end up searching your new files, too.

Answer (score 0):

You might be helped by the `-m` switch of `grep`, which limits the number of search results, e.g. `grep -m 5 "2TQMY" *.annotations` will give you only the five first "2TQMY" instances of every "*.annotations" file.

See `man grep` excerpt:

```
-m NUM, --max-count=NUM
  Stop  reading a file after NUM matching lines.
  ...
```